# get rows between two date range in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I wrote the following query to fetch rows from database between two given date range.But it is not fetching any data.What is wrong in this query and how it can be fixed

```
$from=date_format(date_create($this->input->post('from_date')),'ym');
$to=date_format(date_create($this->input->post('to_date')),'ym');
               $this->db->from('tab1');
               $this->db->join('tab2','tab1.party_id=tab2.party_id','inner');
               $this->db->where("EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM tab2.incoming_call_date ) BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to}");
               $query = $this->db->get();
               $data = $query->result();
               return $data;
```

Comment: print your generated query `echo $this->db->last_query()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ym` will output as 2 digit of year and then month. But in mysql you are using `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH...` which output as 4 digit year then month. match this first by using capital `Y`

```
$from=date_format(date_create($this->input->post('from_date')),'Ym');
$to=date_format(date_create($this->input->post('to_date')),'Ym');
```